# Drop down menu not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

Still learning a lot.. But basically finally finished my website, but now I'm failing at getting it to work in all browsers, fine in Chrome and Firefox, also checking on Browser testing websites, seems fine in Opera as well, but as per usual, Internet Explorer refuses to play nice and the menu's just fail to load all together.

Here is the Nav HTML;

```
 <div id="nav">
            <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="index.php"  class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=645">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="?page_id=645">Gemini Global</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?page_id=647">Joe Davenport</a></li>


                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=435">Services</a>
                                            <ul>
                        <li><a href="?page_id=623">Implement & Marketing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?page_id=625">Analysis & Evaluation</a></li>   
                        <li><a href="?page_id=628">Bid Writing</a></li>


                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="?page_id=38">News</a></li>

                <li><a href="?page_id=275">Contact</a></li>
            </ul><!-- #topnav -->
        </div><!-- #nav -->
```

and here is the CSS;

```
/*** TOP AREA & MENU ***/
#top{height:77px; clear:both}


#topsearch{ float:right; padding:25px 0 0 0}
#topsearch .inputbox{width:200px; padding:6px 5px; background:#fff url(../images/bg_searchtop.gif) repeat-x; border:solid 1px #fff; outline:solid 1px #eaeaea; color:#6e6e6e; font-size:12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #d3d3d3;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #d3d3d3;

}


#nav{position:relative; z-index:100; clear:both; height:70px;}

#topnav{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"DroidSansRegular";
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:url(../images/nav_line.gif) repeat-y  left top;
  }

.sf-menu > li{background:url(../images/nav_line.gif) repeat-y  right top; width:156.667px; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0; height:54px; line-height:54px}

.sf-menu a:hover{color:#f0b028;}
.sfHover a, .sfHover a.sf-with-ul {color:#f0b028;}
.sfHover li a.sf-with-ul { color:#303030!important; }
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a { color:#303030; }
.sf-menu a {
    color:#303030; text-decoration:none!important;
    display:        block;
    position:       relative;
    padding:        0 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.sf-menu li a.current{color:#0062a7;}

.sf-menu li li:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f4f5f5;
}
.sfHover{background:#ca0005;}


/* Drop down menu */
.sf-menu ul a:hover {
    background:transparent; 
}
.sf-menu li li {
    background:#f3f3f3 url(../images/bg_submenu.gif) repeat-x 0 -1px !important; 
    border-top:1px solid #e4e4e4;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin:         0;
    padding:        0;
    list-style:     none;
    font-size:13px;

}
.sf-menu {
    line-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    float:left;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    position:       absolute;
    top:            -999em;
    width:          27em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
    border:solid 1px #e4e4e4;
    border-top:0;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
    width:          100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
    visibility:     inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
    float:          left;
    position:       relative;
    margin:0;
}

.sf-menu li li{margin:0px 0px;}


.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left:           -2px;
    top:            4.4em; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;

}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           10em; /* match ul width */
    top:            -1px;
    margin-left:    0px;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;

}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           10em; /* match ul width */
    top:            -1px;

}
.sf-menu ul li a{
    font-size:11px;
    padding:10px 25px 10px 25px!important;
    color:#303030;
}

.sf-menu ul li a:hover{}
.sf-menu li ul {
    padding:0px;
}
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right:  0px;
    min-width:      1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
    position:       absolute;
    display:        block;
    right:          10px;
    top:            1.05em; /* IE6 only */
    width:          10px;
    height:         10px;
    text-indent:    -999em;
    overflow:       hidden;
}
```

Jsfiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/CsKtv/

Comment: you have a couple of unmatched `</li>` tags though i doubt that's causing your issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your html as below. Your html casuing issue.

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php"  class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="?page_id=645">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?page_id=645">Gemini Global</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?page_id=647">Joe Davenport</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="?page_id=435">Services</a>
                     <ul>
                    <li><a href="?page_id=623">Implement & Marketing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?page_id=625">Analysis & Evaluation</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="?page_id=628">Bid Writing</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>

            <li><a href="?page_id=38">News</a></li>

            <li><a href="?page_id=275">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!-- #topnav -->
    </div><!-- #nav -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Life saver!  I can figure out what I've done wrong now, just being slow im guessing.. haha! thank you!

Comment: not a problem :o)   Only thing is IE takes html validation seriously. Any mistake in start and end tag sequence can brake code function.

Comment: The tags are still improperly nested in the fourth <li>. A <ul> is closed prior to the nested <li> being closed. Might want to edit the post. Otherwise, good job. :D

Answer (score 2):

Definitely mismatched tags. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/8M7gu/)

I tested this in IE8 and works fine once the tags are proper.

Comment: Could you check out the full site? Im still a bit confused from what you sent me.. sorry! Still learning coding stuff! thanks!
http://www.hobhob.co.uk/geminiglobal

Comment: thanks! figured it out now :)

Comment: So basically chrome is handling the malformed HTML better than IE. What's happening is your sub list under "About" starts with a UL, but the LI tag for About ends before the sub list is ended. Basically the tags are out of order. It needs to mimic this methodology `<ul><li></li></ul>`, but you currently have `<ul><li></ul></li>`